# Caesar Cipher Simple Program

Tags: c, encryption

I've taken a code from [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/109509-simple-cipher-program.html) for a simple Caesar cipher, and I've modified it so that the user will define the cipher key. But the program crashes every time I tried to run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char array[100], cipher[100];
    int c=0, x=0, y=0;
    int z;
    printf("This Program will encrypt according to your needs\n");
    printf("Enter the cipher key\n");
    scanf("%d",&z);
    printf("Enter the sentence");
    while((c=getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        array[x++]=(char)c;
        cipher[y++]=(char)(c+z);
    }

    array[x]=0;
    cipher[y]=0;

    printf("%s\n",cipher);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if it crashes use a debugger, there was once a time when I debugged with log statements ... the hours that I could have saved by spending an hour learning how to use a debugger... I was dumb, you don't have to be.

Comment: what's the problem in your code? i tried it and it does not crash

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't crash. The while loop ends instantly since the '\n' is in input buffer after scanf and this gets read first

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` that reads in the key leaves a newline in the input buffer.  Then when you call `getchar` for the first time, it returns `\n`, so the `while` loop is never entered.

You're not actually crashing, but just never getting an opportunity to enter in the string to encode.

You need to add an extra call to `getchar` after the `scanf` but before the loop to consume the newline:

```
scanf("%d",&z);
getchar();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void main()
{
    char p[20];
    int key,i,enc;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter Plain text=");
    gets(p);
    printf("\n Enter Key=");
    scanf("%d",&key);

    for(i=0;i<strlen(p);i++)
    {
           p[i]=tolower(p[i]);
           enc=((p[i]-97)+key)%26;
           printf("%c",enc+97);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the explanation as well. I can see that the user returning a 0 is kind of saying program is completed and exit the program and only difference the getch() method call does is to wait for user to key in any input if that is what you intended to explain please let us know how it makes the difference.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
    {
    int i, c;
    char str[100];

    printf("Enter the Text Message : ");
    gets(str);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
        switch (str[i])
            {
            case 'x':
                str[i] = 'a';
                continue;
            case 'y':
                str[i] = 'b';
                continue;
            case 'z':
                str[i] = 'c';
                continue;
            case 'X':
                str[i] = 'A';
                continue;
            case 'Y':
                str[i] = 'B';
                continue;
            case 'Z':
                str[i] = 'C';
                continue;
            }

        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] < 'x')
            str[i] = str[i] + 3;
        else if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] < 'X')
            str[i] = str[i] + 3;
        }

    printf("Message After Encryption : \n");
    puts(str);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
        switch (str[i])
            {
            case 'a':
                str[i] = 'x';
                continue;
            case 'b':
                str[i] = 'y';
                continue;
            case 'c':
                str[i] = 'z';
                continue;
            case 'A':
                str[i] = 'X';
                continue;
            case 'B':
                str[i] = 'Y';
                continue;
            case 'C':
                str[i] = 'Z';
                continue;
            }

        if (str[i] >= 'd' && str[i] <= 'z')
            str[i] = str[i] - 3;
        else if (str[i] >= 'D' && str[i] < 'Z')
            str[i] = str[i] - 3;

        }
    printf("Message After Decryption : \n");
    puts(str);
    getch();
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code and add a phrase to explain how this answers the question.

Comment: Please note that [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char in[MAXSIZE];
    char en[MAXSIZE] = {0};

    //Input any Sting to encrypt in upper case or lower case
    //or also mixed-up in any case.
    read(STDIN_FILENO, in, MAXSIZE);
    encrypt(in, en);    
    printf("%s\n%s\n", in, en);
    bzero(in, strlen(in));
    decrypt(en, in);
    printf("%s\n%s\n", en, in);
    return 0;
}

int encrypt(char* input, char* cipher)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
    {
        if(input[i] >= 97 && input[i] <= 122)
        {
            cipher[i] = input[i]+23 <= 122 ? input[i] + 23 : input[i] - 3;
        }else if(input[i] >= 65 && input[i] <= 90)
        {
            cipher[i] = input[i]+23 <= 90 ? input[i] + 23 : input[i] - 3;
        }else
            cipher[i] = input[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

int decrypt(char* cipher, char* output)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(cipher); i++)
    {
        if(cipher[i] >= 97 && cipher[i] <= 122)
        {
            output[i] = cipher[i]-23 >= 97 ? cipher[i] - 23 : cipher[i] + 3;
        }else if(cipher[i] >= 65 && cipher[i] <= 90)
        {
            output[i] = cipher[i]-23 >= 65 ? cipher[i] - 23 : cipher[i] + 3;
        }else
            output[i] = cipher[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is much less valuable.

Comment: Note that `read()` does not null terminate the data, so there isn't a string to process.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a complete code in C for Caesar cipher

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i,key;
    char plain[100],cipher[100];
    printf("Enter key:");
    scanf("%d",&key);
    key=key%26; // adjusting key
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter text:");
    gets(plain);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(plain);i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(plain[i]))
        {
            if(islower(plain[i]))
                cipher[i]=(plain[i]+key-'a')%26+'a';
            else
                cipher[i]=(plain[i]+key-'A')%26+'A';
        }
        else
            cipher[i]=plain[i];
    }
    cipher[i]='\0';
    printf("After ciphering: %s",cipher);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)